# public ressources not accessible

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm tring to access the bundles directory (which is located in : /usr/src/app/public/bundles) of my symfony project.
But, all files in public dir can't be accessed with my navigator. eg:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/bundles/easyadmin/app.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

The file exists...

This is my nginx config :

```
server {
    server_name ~.*;

    location / {
        root /usr/src/app;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST|PATCH|DELETE)") {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
        }

        # Preflighted requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            return 200;
        }

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/public/index.php;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

I don't know what is missconfigured...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any error log I can just guess the issue but lets check directories you are using.

First of all try to avoid `root` in locations.

Putting root inside of a location block will work and it’s perfectly valid. What’s wrong is when you start adding location blocks. If you add a root to every location block then a location block that isn’t matched will have no root. Therefore, it is important that a root directive occur prior to your location blocks, which can then override this directive if they need to.

The configuration should look like this:

```
root /usr/src/app/public/;
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Your `location` is missing the `public` directory. So why do see the 404:

For this request `http://localhost:8080/bundles/easyadmin/app.css` with your configuration NGINX will look into `/usr/src/app/` for /bundles/easyadmin/app.css`. And it will not be able to find it. But` /usr/src/app/public/bundles/easyadmin/app.css` will be a valid path and should result in 200 OK.

Comment: Resolved: I had an error with my docker configuration. The volume configured was wrong
Thanks for your help